# A Legitimate Sequence

Tags: letter-sequence, sequence

Choices:

> A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

Sequence:

> D G A B I L F ? ?

As long as you can count you can solve this puzzle.

So what could the next letters be?

Comment: Are we seeking TWO letters, or is ? ? standing for a single continuation only?

Comment: @BmyGuest letter*s* 2

Comment: Could the answer depend on the actual used font or face of the letters?

Comment: Yes @kamenf ${}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we set some presumptions (explained later) it could be:

> E J

Reasoning:

> We count the number of straight lines visible in the letters. Here I assume in the font used (at least the one I see on my monitor) to present letters the D is formed with a vertical line and semicircle, B is formed from E by adding 2 semicircles, and G has one vertical and one horizontal line. So D has 1 and is the first choice from choices with 1 line, G has 2, A - 3, B - 4, then we start over from one (since there are no letters with 5 lines) and the next letters with corresponding number of lines are I - 1, L - 2, F - 3. So the next letter with 4 lines is E, the next with 1 line could be J.

Comment: That is _exactly_ what I thought of as well.  But the 'J' in the font I see has a little bit of a serif at the top, so it seemed ambiguous.

Comment: I was thinking it might be this, but the B didn't seem to fit as well, since I only see it as having 3 lines.

Comment: @KeyboardWielder D, B and G are far more ambiguous in my opinion, but... that's what I came up with so far. :)

Comment: Nicely done. This is *precisely* why I listed the options rather than implying them. To stress the importance of how the letters are formed

Answer (score 0):

G O R L M U X R S

because the sequence is such: **|+3|-6|+1|+8** where | means the current letter and it counts as many positions as I indicate between these '|' characters to get to the next letter

**D** +3 **G** -6 **A** +1 **B** +8 **I** +3 **L** -6 **F** +1 **G** +8 **O** +3 **R** -6 **L** +1 **M** +8 **U** +3 **X** -6 **R** +1 **S**

THIS IS THE SEQUENCE I SEE

> PS.: I post a comment here because I don't have enough reputation to
>   comment on your post @kamenf
>
> If B has 4 lines, the D has 3, because the D and B have this same
>   structure: [. Then is completed with semi-circles.

Answer (score -2):

The next letters are :

> G N Q K and henceforth, I believe
> So yeah, G N are the next two if im correct

Because :

> The puzzle starts from D, skips 2 to G, skips 2 backwards from D to A, skips 1 backwards from D to B and then skips 4 from D to I. Now, I as centre, skips 2 to L, skips 2 backwards to F and now it should skip 1 backwards to G, then skip forwards 4 spaces to N to now focus on N as centre and continue and therefore, G and N might be the next two.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Would you be so kind and explain why your answer is correct?

Comment: The puzzle starts from D, skips 2  to G, skips 2 backwards from D to A, skips 1 backwards from D to B and then skips 4 from D to I. Now, I as centre, skips 2 to L, skips 2 backwards to F and now it should skip 1 backwards to G, then skip forwards 4 spaces to N to now focus on N as centre and continue and therefore, G and N might be the next two.